# BigCommerce stencil bundle theme validating issues in schema.json file

Tags: json, npm, bigcommerce

Hello developers out here!

I struggle with **stencil bundle** and **stencil push** issues.

I get error at "*Validating theme...*"

```
Error: Your theme's schema.json has errors:
schema[1].settings[28].options[0].value should be string,number
schema[1].settings[28].options[1].value should be string,number
...
```

It seems that I get this issue after try to test latest **cornerstone** (5.4.5) theme version, and update stencil-cli  and now I can't use oldest version (1.10.0) schema.json file -> https://github.com/bigcommerce/cornerstone/blob/1.10.0/schema.json

Now it only works with these two files:

- schema.json -> https://github.com/bigcommerce/cornerstone/blob/4.5.4/schema.json
- schemaTranslations.json -> https://github.com/bigcommerce/cornerstone/blob/4.5.4/schemaTranslations.json

But I am not sure how it would impact live site work if I use different schema files.

It is possible to work again with old schema.json file?
Previously all worked...

I tried to:

1. delete all node_modules
2. reinstall @bigcommerce/stencil-cli
3. and node modules (npm install)

Answer (score 0):

These look similar to errors when the schema.json or schemaTranslations.json file have been removed or modified, could you add any relevant schema code in your post? Since Stencil CLI 2.0, part of the bundle process now validates a schemaTranlsations.json file which has been included since Cornerstone 4.5.4. This change can be found on the GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/bigcommerce/cornerstone/pull/1644) as well as on our [DevCenter Changelog](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/changelog#posts/cornerstone-4-5-4).

Comment: Yes I was readed that. It seems I resolve this issue with changing node version from **10.16.3** to **8.16.2** and now I can execute stencil push and stencil bundle functions.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @dakterits and @kyle-obrien

The error which you mentioned means that option number 0 and 1 in setting number 28 in the schema file has either empty value or different value. So, to fix this issue, you don't have downgrade the node or reinstall stencil or delete any file.

The Solution:

1. Download the original copy of the theme.
2. Edit the original theme schema file.
3. If you have any file compare software then compare edited theme schema with original theme schema.
4. Once you compare, you will definitely see any change in value in defined settings.